# PasteSpecial only values

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I want to copy paste a range of cells into a destination sheet, but only their values, not the format. Unfortunately, my code pastes the format, too. I am providing the line of code for this purpose. (I know how to paste special values but I want, if it is possible, to apply this method for this method of copy paste. Normally, I use a different copy paste method, for which I know how to paste special, but for this time I wanted to keep the length of the macro as small as possible).

```
ws1.Range("C2:C" & lastrow2).Copy ws2.Range("A2")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would recommend:

```
ws2.Range("A2:A" & lastrow2).Value = ws1.Range("C2:C" & lastrow2).Value
```

Comment: Ok great!! I will use this one :)

Comment: @Jeeped Thanks; just quick typed it like a fool... was still thinking xlPasteValues

Answer (score 1):

Try a direct value transfer.

```
with ws1.Range("C2:C" & lastrow2)
     ws2.Range("A2").resize(.rows.count, .columns.count) = .value
end with

'alternately,
ws2.Range("A2").resize(ws1.Range("C2:C" & lastrow2).rows.count, ws1.Range("C2:C" & lastrow2).columns.count) = ws1.Range("C2:C" & lastrow2).value
```

Comment: thank you very much buddy! Its a great solution but I normally use exactly this one, so I will try to avoid it due to length issues.. nevertheless, thank you again!!

Comment: Just remember that this method does not rely on the source and target originating on the same row while the other answer does.

Comment: yes I understand that :) so, it is impossible to let’s say add a xlValues to my initial line of code so as to work as I am trying to make it work ? I want to make it work in one line if it is possible .. the other solution solved my problem but still as you said it has to have same rows !

Comment: I've added an alternate for one line.